What is the relation between bicycle rear wheel path and front wheel path?
I'm not a physicist, more of a mathematician. I want to solve a puzzle which apparently requires the physical knowledge of how front wheel path (F) and rear wheel path (R) of one and the same bicycle are related. I found the following mathematical model:
$$F(t) = R(t) + L · R′(t)/
|R′(t)|, $$
where $L$ is the distance between front and rear axle.
I don't understand the physics behind this model at all. The source where I found that model merely states that 'the model follows directly from bicycle physics'. I don't have a clue. Can anyone here explain, in terms of forces, position of front axle, its displacement, etc., how precisely this model matches the material world?
In particular, since rear wheel curve is determined by front wheel displacement over time, why do you express F in terms of R, not vice versa? I'd like to see—mathematically, explicitly and solely in terms of the resulting curves R and F, and maybe "relatives" of F (including maps; strictly speaking, a 'curve' is just a set, as opposed to a 'path', which definetly is a map)—how my controlling (via handlebars) of front wheel displacement brings about rear wheel curve. The model above is implicit.

Can you specify where this equation is from? This is actually exactly the opposite of what I would expect. I would have thought it makes more sense to write the trajectory of the rear wheel in terms of the direction of the front wheel.

I agree. That would be my approach, too. Rear wheel position obviously is determined by front wheel position (displacement) in conjunction with thrust from behind. And the displacement of front wheel is what's controlled by the handlebars. So I don't understand the rationale of that model. The latter seems to turn the whole matter upside down. Problem is, that model is unanimously taken for granted again and again, in this thread, too. I'll just wait and see…

In summary: Natural approach seems to be to represent  R in terms of F, not the other way round.

@Amit: See https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/igt/eiserm/lehre/Hoehere-Mathematik-3/HM3-E-2x2.pdf and look out for 'Sherlock Holmes' puzzle.

Thanks, I've deleted my comment because I was actually about to answer, but I have to tie some loose ends first. Perhaps tomorrow :)

Here the same matter in general press, not scientific literature, action: https://www.spiegel.de/karriere/raetsel-der-woche-in-welche-richtung-fuhr-das-fahrrad-a-c06759ab-79b5-42aa-b958-1cb6afb529a7

I don't like the above press puzzle: So much prerequisites hold back or left to the reader, it's annoying. For example: Trail diagram doesn't offer any scale. Puzzle doesn't specify whether bicycle moved forward(s) only, or potentially backward(s), or halted.

well, a completely unrelated tip is to study physics from physics textbooks, lectures, etc. but not from puzzles :) but I suspect you kind of know that already. At any rate, I suspect that part of the point of a puzzle is often not to give too much background to the reader, either to encourage the reader to do his own research, or because the target audience is assumed to have background in the subject matter...

Puzzles differ in quality. The puzzle in question here cannot be solved. The alleged bicycle trail depicted therein may represent a 20cm section from a 100m long trail, or a 5m section from 5.1m trail. Each serious geographic map has a scale. The same goes for trail representations, which ARE physcial maps actually.

Oh, you may be right. I honestly didn't read it that carefully (and the link is not in a language I understand actually, so I had to resort to automatic translation by the browser, which always gives questionable results...). I was just giving generic advice, and sorry if it isn't relevant here :)

Article is in German. More importantly, do you agree that the bicycle trail diagram in such a puzzle MUST provide sufficient hint as to its scale? Because otherwise, the width of the trail section depicted by the diagram may be (much) less than the distance between front and rear axle ?

Also, let's say we have an accurate diagram D of a finite trail T of a two-wheeled bicycle which moves in one direction only and never halts except at end of trail. The same diagram, D, is also produced by the same bicycle moving the same way in the same manner—AND THEN BACKWARDS WITHIN THE PRE-EXISITNG TRAIL BACK TO THE START. In both cases the result is D. Thus even the question itself—Did the bicycle move forward either from left to right or right to left or are both cases possible ?—is faulty, because it holds back other possible scenarios.

if you want, you can try and ask a separate question about how to apply physics to solve such puzzles, and whether they are even soluble, etc.  We shouldn't use the comments for extended discussion about this here, and it sounds like it can be a perfectly legitimate question, it's just a different one than this. Also, see if the answer I just posted helps in any way.

We can gain some insight into this relation if we note that the velocity vector of the rear wheel must be at every instant proportional to the vector pointing along the body of the bike itself:
$$ \dot{\vec{R}}=\frac{\vec{F}-\vec{R}}{\left|\left|\vec{F}-\vec{R}\right|\right|}v_{\small R} \ , \tag{1}$$
where $v_{\small R}$ will have units of speed, as it is multiplied by a unit vector which is always dimensionless.
Now this allows us to also express $\vec{R}$ in terms of $\vec{F}$, which I think is what you are aiming for in your question:
$$ \vec{R} = \vec{F}-\frac{L}{v_{\small R}}\dot{\vec{R}}\ , \tag{2}$$
where I've substituted $\left|\left|\vec{F}-\vec{R}\right|\right| = L$.
Now, to see an example of how steering, i.e. setting $\vec{F}$ to be a certain curve affects the trajectory of the back wheel position $\vec{R}$, we need to choose some explicit curve for $\vec{F}$. For example, let's introduce some coordinates and let $\vec{F}$ move in a circular trajectory a distance $r_0$ from the origin:
$$ \vec{F} = r_{\small 0}(\cos\omega t\  \hat{x} + \sin\omega t\ \hat{y}) $$
So that using $(2)$ to solve for $\vec{R}$, we get a couple of differential equations:
$$ R_x(t) = r_{\small 0}\cos\omega t - \frac{L}{v_{\small R}} \dot{R_x}(t) $$
$$ R_y(t) = r_{\small 0}\sin\omega t - \frac{L}{v_{\small R}} \dot{R_y}(t) $$
There is more than one possible solution, let's focus on one of the simpler ones that doesn't involve an exponential:
$$ \vec{R} = \frac{r_0 v_{\small R}}{\omega^2 L^2 + v_{\small R}^2}\left[\left( \omega L\sin\omega t + v_{\small R} \cos\omega t  \right)\hat{x}+ \left(-\omega L\cos\omega t + v_{\small R} \sin\omega t\right)  \hat{y}\right],$$
and applying the normalization condition implied by $(1)$, that $\Big|\Big|\dot{\vec{R}}\Big|\Big| = v_{\small R}$ we also find that the angular frequency $\omega$ must satisfy:
$$ \omega = \frac{v_{\small R}}{\sqrt{r_0^2-L^2}}. $$
I've checked via Geogebra if this gives a sensible result, here is an example capture of what I got:

The green track represents the front wheel, the red the back one. You can also interact with this demonstration here.
Despite clearly being a toy model, I think this is what you'd reasonably expect. For example try setting $r_0$ to the possible minimum (which I've limited to be always slightly more than $L$). In that case, the situation corresponds to spinning the bike around itself, with the back wheel remaining nearly stationary. So at least this, as a "sanity check", seems to correspond to what you'd observe in reality. Hope this helps!

An added note, to respond to your remark that this is an implicit model, and hence seems to be less useful in getting a feel for the underlying physics/dynamics. I was also slightly surprised at first, and expected it to be different.
Then I realized, the nice thing about expressing the relation that way is that it makes the minimum possible assumptions about the path that the bicycle can take. It only uses a very simple geometrical fact, which as pointed out by @ThePhoton here, is more a consequence of geometry than of dynamics/kinematics.
This is powerful because, it's a great starting point from which to begin investigating any concrete example, like the very simple one I presented here. We could make a model that introduces two different direction vectors, one that the front steering wheel is pointing along, call it $\hat{n}_{\small F}$, and a second one which is always parallel to the bicycle, $\hat{n}_{\small B}$, but then we would have a much more complicated equation involving both these vectors, and implicitly that means also the angles they make with respect to each other, which is also dependent on time of course.
Now, I'm not saying that couldn't be useful too. There are many ways to model a system. I am only stressing that it is in fact a theme in physics to find the simplest, daresay most abstract, relations first, and then add any complexity on top of that. It would inevitably mean that our starting point is more "implicit" as you say, but it also means it is very general, hence it makes for a good foundation for further development, and for the exploration of any concrete physical situation.

Recommended reference:
Bor, Gil & Levi, Mark & Perline, Ron & Tabachnikov, Serge. (2017). Tire track geometry and integrable curve evolution. 10.48550/arXiv.1705.06314. 

I agree. The whole idea of the above-mentioned puzzle seems to be 'The two curves (not paths or any other additional data) suffice.' to settle the question. Still, the puzzle has some specific prerequisites, and these should be stated clearly.

Yes, one of the problems mentioned in the paper I cited, is how to construct ambiguous bicycle tracks. So those definitely exist. You may also be interested to take a look at "D. Finn. Which way did you say that bicycle went? Math. Mag. 77 (2004)", which is cited in the paper I cited.. and deals with this type of problem precisely, constructing ambiguous tracks. Also see this book, and maybe best of all this nice page

I'm still studying your papers. Suddenly, I don't understand the initial model (see initial post) anymore: What happens when R'(t) is the zero vector? Is the model only for a bicycle that never halts? I mean, R andf F are just paths into 2-dimensional Euclidean space, so R'(t) is a real-valued pair representing the slope in each dimension, isn't it?

@Peterש yes I think it's implicit in this model that the velocity vector can't vanish. You can also see this in my answer by noting that $(1)$ is still fine if $v_{\small{R}}=0$, but if we carry that to $(2)$ we get an undefined expression because we divide by zero. So you're right, the model cannot incorporate cases where at any time $t$ we have $\dot{\vec{R}}=0$. But I don't see that as a big issue because a stationary bicycle doesn't require a differential equation as a model, and we can always "stitch up" several solutions if we want to add the bike as being stationary in between :)

Yes, each time interval of non-zero movement can be treated seperately. But is my physical interpretation of R'(t) correct: The first component of R'(t) is the gradient of 'horizontal' movement at point t, and the second the gradient of 'vertical' movement at t, where 'gradient' is a limit (slope) mathematically.

@Peterש Yes, assuming we write this vector in Cartesian coordinates. But vectors are geometric objects and don't have to be thought of in a specific coordinate system. It may be more helpful for you to note that a velocity vector, is always tangent to the path taken by the moving object. To see why, note that: $$ \dot{\vec{R}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{R}}{\mathrm{d}t}, $$ hence, we may write: $$ \mathrm{d}\vec{R} =  \dot{\vec{R}}\mathrm{d}t,$$ so that we see $\dot{\vec{R}}$ generates a displacement tangent to the path in interval $dt$, which is a "small" differential vector $\mathrm{d}\vec{R}$

I quote 'It may be more helpful for you to note that a velocity vector, is always  to the path taken by the moving object.'. Exactly. The line generated by R'(t)—iff R'(t) is not zero —is tangential to curve R at point R(t). (Note that R needn't be injective, so R(t) may be met multiple times with potentially different tangents.) That's why I wasn't speaking of veloctiy (physics). I tried to be purely geometrical. The puzzle is essentially geometrical, although some important properties (e.g. smoothness!) of R and F are guaranteed by being bicycle tracks.

@Peterש ok so I hope all is clear, I merely pointed out that decomposing the velocity into vertical and horizontal components implies a choice of a special basis. But yeah you got the correct idea anyway.

One more question though (I'm willing to delete our conversation later, if the rules here demand it.): Assuming the bicycle initially starts moving forward, then halts (speed is zero) at time point t, changes handlebar to another orientation and thus  front wheel displacement, and then starts moving forward again. Then the resulting rear wheel path R is   at t, is it?

@Peterש Correct. I recommend you to watch this on YouTube. click on the link, but don't run the video backwards because I've inserted a timestamp into the link. At exactly the point I link to, a case where the path is not smooth is explained, as part of a broader point about polygonal closed paths. After you see that, I actually do recommend you watch this entire video. It can be very relevant in the context of the riddle you mentioned.

Thus we have a property P1 which any correct statement S of the above-mentioned puzzle must have: S must state clearly that ZERO SPEED is not allowed. Another such property, P2, is this: S must state clearly that the DISTANCE BETWEEN FRONT AND REAR AXLE is well within the dimensions of the bicycle trail illustration. Why do I say that? Because LOTS of puzzles of this kind neglect P1 or P2 or both. One of them is in the video.

Also, the video features a reasoning as to which of the two tracks in the bicycle trail illustration belongs to front and rear wheel, respectively. That reasoning is wrong. It claims that the front wheel track illustration oscillates more than that of the rear wheel track. This is not generally true, especially if the distance between rear and front axle exceeds illustration dimensions.

@Peterש I'm not sure what is the purpose of this discussion now in the comments... I can only reiterate my suggestion from earlier, that if you have a new question, feel free to post it! However, note that after a bit more thought, I concur that a question about this type of puzzle may be better suited for Math.SE than Physics.SE. Just a general suggestion, in case you do post a question. See example of a question posted on Math.SE, about the same subject.

The equation is an approximation to the wheel path - it ignores factors such as rake and the natural tilt that a bicycle takes when turning.
A reasonable model of a bicycle path is to consider the following:

The rear wheel is mounted on a rigid frame oriented in the direction the rear wheel is moving.
The front wheel is mounted at distance L forwards of the rear wheel, on the same rigid frame, but can pivot on a vertical axis.

As a result, the rear wheel is always pointing directly at the front wheel, so you can consider that at any time $t$, if the rear wheel is at a point $R(t)$, then the the front wheel is at a point distance $L$ along a line tangent to $R(t)$.
Maybe the picture below will help.
Addendum for F(t) -> R(t)
WRT the OP's question as to whether there is a solution for $R(t)$ as a function of $F(t)$, the relationship is not quite so simple. For any $R(t)$ (and its derivatives) there is exactly one solution for $F(t)$, but for any $F(t)$, $R(t)$ will depend on both $F(t)$ and some initial value for $R(t0)$. For example: consider $F(t) = (vt,0)$, i.e. the front wheel moves along teh $x$-axis at a constant velocity $v$.
A: If at $t=0$ the rear wheel is at $(-L,0)$, then the rear wheel will also track along the $x$-axis at velocity $v$.
B: If at $t=0$ the rear wheel is at $(0,L)$, then the rear wheel will initially move in the $-y$ direction and will follow a path vaguely remeniscent of an exponential decay that asymptotes to the $x$-axis at large $t$.
C: If at $t=0$ the rear wheel exactly at $(L,0)$, then the rear wheel will theoretically also track along the $x$-axis at velocity $v$. But that is an unstable equilibrium. Even the tiniest $y$ component in its initial position will result in the rear wheel curving off the $x$-axis, stopping momentarily at some $(x,L)$, and then following a path like that in B above.
Maybe another picture will help:



I agree with your explanation. When both curves are given, the relation between F and R specified above IS a major relation between the two. What motivates my question, I think, is this: Is there any simple perspective on the matter (i.e. the relation between F and R) that 'proceeds' from F to R, or derives R from F, rather than starting with R and arriving at F.

Just another thought: Having found one major relation between R and F, why stop there? Maybe there is more to discover?

I think the latter relationship is a bit more complicated. $F(t)$ is solely dependent on $R(t)$, so for any $R(t)$ there can only be one solution for $F(t)$. But any $F(t)$ will have infimitely many possible $R(t)$, depending on the initial value of $R(t0)$.

@Peterש see comment above and edit to my post.

I like the added details in the latest edit. I think that one solution to the example you gave is actually a well known curve called Tractrix. Are those diagrams from a simulation or somewhere else?

I agree. In my questions I always meant 'R in terms of F, any 'relatives' of F (and some initial position of R)', but failed to say it.

@Amit Nope, just freehand drawn form a though experiment - using a very old copy of Illustrator :)

Oh, good visual thinking there!!

$\frac{R'(t)}{|R'(t)|}$ is a unit direction vector in the direction the rear wheel is moving.
Your formula basically says that the front wheel is exactly distance $L$ in front of the rear wheel, and "straight ahead" of it in the direction of motion.
It's not so much caused by "bicycle physics" as by bicycle geometry. If the bicycle frame is completely rigid then the front wheel will always be directly in front of the rear wheel and the rear wheel will always be pointed along the "forward" direction of the frame.
That said, in real bicycles the front forks have a slight "rake" away from the axis of rotation of the handlebars, so that when the wheel is turned the axel will no longer be exactly aligned with the frame, and therefore the model will not be exactly correct:

(image source: vvolt.com)
In comments you added:

Natural approach seems to be to represent R in terms of F, not the other way round.

One of the joys of learning physics is that sometimes you find out that by changing the way you think about a problem you can find a simpler or more elegant way to solve the problem. So even though writing R(t) as a function of F(t) might seem more "natural" initially, here we found a very simple way to write F(t) as a function of R(t), so we might rather reconsider what is "natural" than try to create a clumsier or more complicated model based on our initial conceptualization of the problem.

Nice diagram. Makes things clear regarding bicycle anatomy. But see my comments above: Natural approach would be to express R in terms of F, not vice versa, wouldn't it?

You should edit your question post to make clear what question you want us to answer.

Done. Again, done.

In your answer you comment on my comment. I agree with your comment.  Thinking can result in changing your perspective. On the other hand, it's legitimate to ask questions. So is there a model of type "R(t) = 'something in terms of F(t) and its relatives, and not R(t) and its relatives' ?

@Peterש It should be possible to make such a model, but it would be an integral equation and involve both F(t) and F'(t).


The path is describing with the parameter s, which is the line element
thus
$$ F(s)\approx R(s+L)$$
taking Taylor series
$$\vec F(s)=\vec R(s)+\frac{d\vec R}{ds}\,L\quad,\text{with $~s=s(t)~$}\\ F(t)=\vec R(s(t))+\frac{d\vec R}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}\,L
=\vec R(t)+\frac{\dot{\vec{R}}}{|\dot{\vec{R}}|}\,L$$
with $~v=\frac {ds}{dt}=|\dot{\vec{R}}|~$
Notice
this approximation is only  valid if $~L~$ is much smaller then the radius of path curvature
Example : Circular Path
$$\vec R= \left[ \begin {array}{c} r\cos \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right) 
\\ r\sin \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right) \end {array}
 \right]\quad,
\vec F=\left[ \begin {array}{c} r\cos \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right) -\sin
 \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right) L\\ r\sin \left( {
\frac {s}{r}} \right) +\cos \left( {\frac {s}{r}} \right) L
\end {array} \right] 
$$

